# How to fix a query which mixes AND and OR conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle, boolean-logic

I need to query a table with a filtering condition on three columns:

```
select * 
from table a 
where a.order = car 
and a.color !=red 
or a.automatic !=auto
```

This just checks the first conditions and ignores the second one.

I just can't get my head around it :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its not clear from your question but all you probably need is to wrap parens around your OR condition

Given this following table and rows

```
CREATE TABLE table_a 
    (
     id int primary key, 
     a_order varchar2(20), 
     color varchar2(40),
     automatic varchar2(10)
    )

/


INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (1,'car','red','auto')     /
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (2,'car','red','manual')   /
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (3,'car','blue','auto')    /
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (4,'car','blue','manual') /
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (5,'truck','red','auto')   /
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (6,'truck','red','manual') /
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (7,'truck','blue','auto') /
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (8,'truck','blue','manual') /
```

This select statement will return records 2, 3 and 4 since they are all cars and are either blue or manual

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table_a a 
WHERE  a.a_order = 'car' 
       AND ( a.color != 'red' 
              OR a.automatic != 'auto' )
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03a6f/4)

Another option is to do the following using [De Morgan's law](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=the%20negation%20of%20a%20conjunction%20is%20the%20disjunction%20of%20the%20negations&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws&ei=OTOfT_jNGcG46QG2kYmkAg&usg=AFQjCNEL7A8w_gruPMzeBOWR5sUn3HVYwQ) "The negation of a disjunction is the conjunction of the negations."

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table_a a 
WHERE  a.a_order = 'car' 
    AND NOT ( a.color = 'red' 
             AND a.automatic = 'auto' )
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03a6f/6)

Comment: somehow its not working, i tried this but hte query just validates 1st !red and works off that

Comment: can you create a SQL fiddle that demonstrates it

Comment: thx that should work in mot condition but not sure why it was not working here. i just created a subquery in there and then it started workin

Comment: +1 I've a strong personal preference for the query after De Morgan's has been been applied.

Answer (score 2):

The priority of AND is higher than OR logical operator. You can use OR condition within parenthesis.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table_a a 
 WHERE a.a_order = 'car' 
   AND NOT ( a.color = 'red' 
        AND a.automatic = 'auto' )
```